# Python dict into HTML-template (Django)

Tags: python

I have a pythondict with the example format

```
data ={"X":{"0":1234, "1":5678, "2":1234}, "Y": {"0":4567, "1":1234,"2":4456}}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to iterate through the nested data in an HTML template to create a table.

Can you help me?

Comment: Refer to this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Answer (score 0):

View

```
return render('results.html',
        {'object': sorted(data.items())})
```

template

```
{% for key, value in object.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ key }}: </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but unfortunately the template remains completely empty....